# After Update trigger in phpmyadmin need to call a php with passing data

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to create the Trigger which calls a php script and also passes parameters to php

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_test AFTER Update ON table1 where status_message = "done"
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
  \! echo "php /Email.php" >> /tmp/yourlog.txt
END;
```

how can I get data for the row updated.

Regards,
NewDev

Answer (score 0):

Calling external applications from triggers is possible, but not trivial.

One way to do it is using the `sys_exec()` function ( found at this [User-Defined Function](http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_sys/index.php) ).